# React Native - render a list

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following code snippet:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import AlbumDetail from './AlbumDetail';

class AlbumList extends Component {
    state = { albums: [{}, {}, {}] };

    componentWillMount() {
        //console.log('componentWillMount in AlbumList');
        axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
            .then(response => this.setState({ albums: response.data }));
    }

    renderAlbums() {


        this.state.albums.map(album => {


            return (


                <Text key={album.title}>{album.title}</Text>
            );
        });
    }

    render() {
        const movies = this.state.albums.map(album => {


            return (

                <Text key={album.title}>{album.title}</Text>

            );
        });

        return (
            <View>
                {movies}
                {this.renderAlbums()}

            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default AlbumList;
```

The movie list should be printed twice, one because of the `movies` variable and other because of `renderAlbums()` call. However it is only printed once which is because of `movies` variable.  `renderAlbums()` doesn't work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do `return` in `renderAlbums` too.

```
renderAlbums() {
   return this.state.albums.map(album => {
        return (
            <Text key={album.title}>{album.title}</Text>
        );
    });
}
```